# No error message after dragon.py runs

Tags: python, python-idle, game-development

I'm currently beginning the "[Invent Your Own Computer Games w/ Python](https://inventwithpython.com/inventwithpython.pdf)" book, & for some odd reason, despite multiple checks & finding more than a few gaffes (mispelling a variable, using an ';' when ':' is required, etc.), my type up of `dragon.py` refuses to run in IDLE.

Worse, I'm not getting an error message; it simply displays `"RESTART: /Users/yosemite/Documents/dragon.py"` and I'm back at the prompt.  The official version from the site, found [here](http://inventwithpython.com/dragon.py), however, runs perfectly fine.

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here?  Updated:  Here is my code, previously forgot to include it:

```
import random
import time

def displayIntro():

    print ('You are in a land full of dragons.  In front of you.')
    print ('you see two caves.  In one cave, the dragon is friendly.')
    print ('and will share his reasure with you.  The other dragon')
    print ('is greedy and hungry, and will eat you on sight.')
    print()

def chooseCave():
    cave = ''
    while cave != '1' and cave !='2':
        print ('Which cave will you go into?  ( 1 or 2 )')
        cave = input()

    return cave

def checkCave(chosenCave):
    print ('You approach the cave...')
    time.sleep(2)
    print ('It is dark and spooky...')
    time.sleep(2)
    print ('A Large dragon jumps out in front of you!  He opens his jaws 
    and...')
    print()
    time.sleep(2)

    friendlyCave = random.randint(1, 2)

    if chosenCave == str(friendlyCave):
        print('Gives you his treasures!')
    else:
        print('Goobles you up in onebite!')

    playAgain = 'yes'
    while playAgain =='yes' or playAgain == 'y':

        displayIntro()

        caveNumber = chooseCave()

        checkCave(caveNumber)

        print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
        playAgain = input()
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Also, apparently, there is a diff tool for the code samples in that book. Go to [this page](https://inventwithpython.com/diff/?p=dragon), enter your code and see what is different.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. A [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: Ah thanks, will do; apologies for the rough post.  My next post will be more up to code, so to speak.

Comment: Updated w/ code snippet.

Comment: The behavior you see has nothing to do with IDLE other than the fact that IDLE correctly imitates running programs with `python -i`.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted, once indented properly, imports two modules, defines three functions, and then ends.  Displaying the prompt when the program ends is what IDLE is supposed to do.

Adding the following function call at the end gets execution going.

checkCave(chooseCave())

If you had run you program from the (mac?) console with

```
python -i /Users/yosemite/Documents/dragon.py
```

you would have seen the same behavior, the appearance of a `>>>` prompt.